# In Rational (Eclipse), CVS version and CVS url after Project Name

Tags: java, eclipse, cvs

I am using Rational (Eclipse) with CVS, the CVS version and URL use to show after the project name. But somehow they are now showing anymore. 
In Project -> Properties -> CVS, I still need the correct setting for the project. What's the problem? How can make the CVS version and URL to show again?

Answer (score 1):

These are called "Label Decorations". Go to Preferences -> Team, expand CVS, then focus on "Label Decorations".

Comment: Hi Isaac, thanks for the info. I am using the default settings and everything looks good in the Preview window. But somehow the File Decoration, Folder Decoration and Project Decoration still don't show in the Navigation view. Any idea?

Comment: RAD used to have a bug... it wouldn't show the decorations unless you go to one project, right click -> properties, focus on the CVS info, then click OK (without changing anything). You can try that.

Comment: Tried that, still no luck. Thanks anyway.